# My cookies are only available on PHP pages they are set on, is this normal?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I cannot access cookies from any page other than the page they are set on. I looked at `print_r($_COOKIE)` on different pages and the only common variable between pages is the `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']`.

I am developing on a local XAMPP testing server. Is there a setting I should change on the PHP.ini or is this normal behavior for cookies? Sorry, I'm a little new to this stuff and I was under the impression cookies were accessible site wide.

I am setting cookies like:

```
setcookie("user", "Dave Schmave", time()+60*60*24*120);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You might find [`$cookie->setPath($path)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L104) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try setting the cookie path to the root:

```
setcookie("user", "Dave Schmave", time()+60*60*24*120, '/');
```

Also is it on the same domain? Accessing via HTTPS will also affect your cookies.

Comment: That seems to do it. Is this something that could be changed on a global server setting? My php.ini file session.cookie_path is set to '/' but I guess I will still need to declare the root in the setcookie(). Thanks for your help1

Comment: maybe something is overwriting this setting. Try placing a phpinfo() at the location of your script and check the settings :)

Comment: Ah, I had misread the API and was using my domain 'domain.com' here instead of the path.

Comment: This just saved me from a very frustrating time. Great answer, it was exactly I was looking +1